# Shoving two data types into one Persistent entity

Tags: haskell

We cryptographically sign some data using a wrapped type....

```
--Here is the base data
data Fridge = Fridge {numOnions::Int, numPickles::Int} deriving (Show)

--Here is the same data, signed
data SignedFridge = SignedFridge {fridge::Fridge, signature::Int}
```

This is done for type safety (ie- I made the mistake of submitting unsigned `Fridge`s in place of signed one too many times....  With this split, this mistake is weeded out at compile time).

Now, we need to store this data (including signature) into a database....  I would love to use Persistent/Template Haskell, even handing over the data type generation....  But the split of fields across Fridge/SignedFridge seems to make this impossible.  Without the signature, it would be

```
[persistLowerCase|
     Fridge
         numOnions Int
         numPickles Int
         deriving Show
|]
```

However, shoving in that extra `signature` item, and keeping the types split is difficult....

The three (bad) options seem to be

1. Create the PersistEntity instance by hand (ugh!)
2. Use Persistent/TH to create a similar duplicate data type (like SignedFridge', with both the data and signature), then create function to convert back and forth to `SignedFridge`.  This works, but certainly isn't DRY.
3. Lose type safety, store signature in the Fridge object as a `Maybe Int`.  Of course, I won't find out until runtime that I accidentally used an unsigned fridge where I need one signed.

Does anyone have a fourth, better option for me?

Comment: Do you also persist `Fridge`s, or only `SignedFridge`s?

Comment: @Cirdec- Good question!  Let me say "no"....  We don't currently need to store a `Fridge` in the DB.  It may change later on, but if it does, I'll just post a new question (rather than add new and potentially unnecessary criteria to this question after the fact).